# Angular routing not working properly ( path: 'blog/add' )

Tags: angular, routes

Angular router not working properly

Have a look my part of app-routing.module.js code

```
    { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent},
    { path: 'blog/add', component: BlogPostEditComponent},
```

The problem is

> http://localhost:4200/#/blog
>   when hit enter it went to BlogComponent that's fine
>
> http://localhost:4200/#/blog/add
>   when hit enter for this url also it went to BlogComponent , actually it would go to  BlogPostEditComponent 
>   I couldn't understand what's going on?
>
> Anyone can explains why is that ?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: Nope , There are no error in the console @Hunor

Comment: Can you provide StackBlitz Demo so I/we can reproduce?

Comment: Because by looking at your code it is fine might show the Routes array to us so will help

Comment: try this: { path: 'blog/:add', component: BlogPostEditComponent},

Comment: please provide StackBitz demo so that we can solve your routing issue.

Comment: You should configure 'blog/add' as a child route of the 'blog' route

Comment: You do not need the # in the url then it will work.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hum1ji @PrashantPimpale

Comment: child route also not working @AzkarMoulana

Comment: Not working @Luv

Comment: @kobi Incomplete code in the stackblitz

Comment: @kobi please provide a stackblitz sample code

Comment: @kobi https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqtaua  There you go. it had syntax errors plus the # problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 { path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent ,  pathMatch: 'full'},
{ path: 'blog/add', component: BlogPostEditComponent,  pathMatch: 'full'},
```

Just add PathMatch

Answer (score 0):

Routes with matching urls should be related routes.

```
{ path: 'blog', component: BlogComponent, children: [
  { path: 'add', component: BlogPostEditComponent},
]},
```

And next time, please provide a working stackblitz, not just a stackblitz to say you have provided one ...